# Better way to manage libraries required for gems?

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, capistrano, bundler

I consistently run into issues with gems not having the required libraries on a server. RMagick is one, and usually mysql2, which usually require installing the dev versions such as:

imagemagick libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev

My question is, is there a better way to manage this? I'm using bundler and capistrano, so it would be great if somebody could point me in the right direction.

The big problem I can see is that distros will change from server to server, but if I had a task I could run which could check the existence of these required packages based on the Gemfile, that would be tremendously helpful. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend section 'cap deploy:setup'. =And in this section run 'apt-get instal imagemagick libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev'. But you user must have sudo access.

Also you can read [this manual](http://viget.com/extend/building-an-environment-from-scratch-with-capistrano-2)